# Changing Host header in http-request changes the base URL of route() method - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, http-headers, host

When I change the `Host` header of an http-request then Laravel's `route()` method uses that URL as base URL to generate the full URLs.

For eg.

If my website URL is `abc.com` and someone sends a get request with header `Host: evil.com` then all my routes will become `evil.com/about`, `evil.com/dashboard`

So why Laravel is depending on the header provided by the user to generate URLs?

Comment: Have you defined base url in .env? if yes have you tried with url()?

Comment: @Kaleem There is no key like `base_url` in .env file but `APP_URL` is set correctly. And also `APP_URL` is only used when your app is running in console. No, I haven't tried `url()` method but the question is about `route()` method.

Comment: Did you ever find a reason/solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post this if anyone is still interested. The question posted is related to an issue called Host Header injection. I would fix this using a middleware that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class PreventHostHeaderInjection
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $hostHeaderURLObject = parse_url($request->header('HOST'));
        $hostHeader = isset($hostHeaderURLObject['host']) ? $hostHeaderURLObject['host'] : $hostHeaderURLObject['path'];
        $appHost = parse_url(config('app.url'))['host'];
        if ($hostHeader != $appHost) {
            abort(400, 'Bad Request!');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The middleware basically checks if the host header from the request is the same as the host specified in your APP_URL variable in the .env file. Don't forget to add the middleware to the middleware list in your Kernel.php file